# Issues while playing videos in firefox and Ie9.0

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to create flash fallback as I've only MP4 file with me, however it is not working for me.

Your production site is also having same issue, for playing a video in firefox/ie9.

Thanks,
Parimal

Comment: Sir, do you want us to look at Firefox codebase for you?

Answer (score 1):

1. Encode your video using `h264`.
2. Doctype your page as `html5`.
3. Write video tag and add your mp4 file to source.

It assumes that you encode your video with `h264`.